# How to determine some points are inside or outside in triangle

Tags: geometry

[image]
Let i have given some coordinates and i have to test some points  to determine that the points (2, 18), (10, 3 )  is inside or outside of the triangle or not. 
Do I have to use inequality by using the equation $4x+ 3y =60$ ? is there any short and easy technique to do it?

Comment: Is there a reason why you'd want something else? Checking if it satisfies the inequality is just arithmetic. (If you're wanting it for a scenario less simple than the one in your diagram, you should say so in your question.)

Comment: how can i determine from diagram?

Comment: ...draw the diagram, then draw the point accurately and look to see if it lands inside?

Comment: You might want to explore barycentric co-ordinates http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the equation of a line, such as $x=0$ not only gives you a line, it also gives you a half-plane. The half-plane to the right of the $y$-axis is given by $x>0$. Similarly, the half-plane above the $x$-axis is given by $y>0$ and the half-plane below the line $4x+3y=60$ is given by $4x+3y<60$. The intersection of these three half-planes is the interior of the triangle.

So all you have to do is check whether (2,18) satisfies all three to find out if it lies inside the triangle. It obviously satisfies the first two, so you just have to check the third.

Comment: got you. but how did you write the inequality $4x+3y<60$  ?

Comment: You mean how did I know it wasn't $4x+3y>60$? Easy. We know it is a half-plane take a point with huge positive $x$ and huge positive $y$. That is obviously in the wrong half-plane and has $4x+3y>60$, so we want the opposite. Or even easier, try the origin. That is in the right half-plane and satisfies 4x+3y<60.

Comment: i din't get you :( sorry